# YouTube C# API V3, how do you delete a partially uploaded video without the ID?

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

The VideoID is returned in the ResponseReceived event but not before the upload has completed. If the user cancels and deletes the upload, how do you delete it from the YouTube servers?

What I'm currently doing is an ugly but working hack.

I set the title to a unique guid. When the upload completes, I set the correct title.

If the upload is deleted, I get the first channel and search the playlist for the guid title. This returns the VideoID and I can delete the video.

There has to be a better way. Can I use the upload_id from the response?

Comment: I've modified this slightly to add my guid as a tag and then use the search:list to locate it but I'm still looking for a better method.

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone comes up with a better idea, this is what I'm currently doing and it appears to be working quite well. One caveat is the potential for videos to disappear if they happen to have the same guid tag but I don't think that's very likely.

Some constant strings used

```
internal const string PartSnippet = "snippet";
internal const string TypeVideo = "video";
```

Before I kick off the upload, I add a guid tag.

```
video.Snippet.Tags.Add(upload.UploadId.ToString());
```

In the ResponseReceived event, when the upload completes, I remove the tag

```
YouTube.RemoveTag(obj, Upload.UploadId.ToString());

internal static void RemoveTag(Video video, string tag)
{           
    video.Snippet.Tags.Remove(tag);
    var updateRequest = YouTubeService.Videos.Update(video, Constants.PartSnippet);
    updateRequest.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

If the video needs to be removed from the server, I search for it by guid tag and delete it.

```
YouTube.DeleteAsyncVideoByGuidTag(Upload.UploadId);

internal async static Task DeleteAsyncVideoByGuidTag(Guid tag)
{
    var listRequest = YouTubeService.Search.List(Constants.PartSnippet);
    listRequest.ForMine = true;
    listRequest.Type = Constants.TypeVideo;
    listRequest.Q = tag.ToString();
    var response = await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();
    foreach (var deleteRequest in response.Items.Select(
        result => YouTubeService.Videos.Delete(result.Id.VideoId)))             
        await deleteRequest.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Please note: This is a workaround. It's not the way I'd like to do it but it's the only way I can think of doing it.