# How do I delete a resumable upload without the Video Id?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm revisiting a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369100/youtube-c-sharp-api-v3-how-do-you-delete-a-partially-uploaded-video-without-the/22394531#22394531) I asked years ago with no real answer but 800 views. I'm using Google.Apis.YouTube.V3 client framework V1.40.3.1699.

```
var mediaUpload = YouTubeService.Videos.Insert(GetVideoDetails(YouTubeUpload), Constants.PartSnippetStatusDetails, fileStream, Constants.ContentTypeVideo);
mediaUpload.UploadSessionData += mediaUpload_UploadSessionData;
mediaUpload.ProgressChanged += mediaUpload_ProgressChanged;
mediaUpload.ResponseReceived += mediaUpload_ResponseReceived;
await mediaUpload.UploadAsync(CancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

In the UploadSessionData event, we get the ResumeUri but not the Video Id.
In the ProgressChanged event, we get the progress and status but not the Video Id.

We get the Video Id in the ResponseReceived event but this only occurs after the upload completes. I no longer have a use for the Video Id as my application's work is finished.

Cancelling the upload to simulate a pause does not trigger the ResponseReceived event and doesn't give me the Video Id.

1. How do I delete a video without the Video Id?
2. Alternatively, how do I get the Video Id before the upload completes?

This seems like it should be something common and simple but it's evaded me for years. I'd really like to implement a solution if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Video id is probably only returned if the upload is complete.  Have you tried doing a Videos.list to find the find the video id does it show it there?  If not i dont think you need to delete a video that hasnt completed upload as it doesnt exist until the video is completely uploaded.

Comment: The docs state _"Remember that each resumable session URI has a finite lifetime and eventually expires."_, which I'm reading as "the resumable upload eventually expires" (I might be wrong). In that case, do you need to delete it or can you just let it expire?

Comment: @John I normally just let them expire.

Comment: @DaImTo the Video Id exists immediately and the video can be deleted if you have it. As per the linked question, I currently use a guid tag to locate it.

Comment: @John, I never once considered the option of letting it expire. Perfect solution! I'll kick one off and see how long it takes to disappear. This will save me requiring manage account scope. Problem solved. Cheers.

Comment: My test orphaned video has been sitting spinning a little grey icon on a black thumbnail for 15 days without 'disappearing' on it's own. This is unacceptable to me so the original question stands. I'm surprised this is an issue and there isn't an easy way to cancel or abort a resumable upload.

Comment: The orphaned video is still there 28 days later. "Finite lifetime" is a lot longer than expected. With my application, the user could delete a hundred videos leaving them all in this state. I need to delete them. Does anyone have a better idea than tagging them with a guid?